# Lua with user input

Tags: input, lua

What am I doing wrong with this Lua code?
I am trying to generate two random numbers and ask what they are multiplied together.
The first part is good, but no matter what I type as the answer, it always thinks that it is incorrect.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Remember this is Lua.

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local a=math.random(10)
local b=math.random(10)


local answer
repeat
io.write("What is ",a,"*",b,"?")    
io.flush()  
answer=io.read()
if answer==a*b then
print("Correct!")
else
print("Try Again")
end
until
answer==a*b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`io.read()` returns a `string`, and you're comparing it with a number.

You either need to say `answer=tonumber(io.read())`, or you need to say `io.read("*n")`.

Comment: @user2059810 welcome to stackoverflow! consider accepting Kevin's answer (by clicking the check mark) to give him some credit and show future visitors that (and how) your problem has been solved